# Grant Access Denied

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

When I import dbback file to my test mysql server,I found I lost all account.
so I use `skip-grant-tables`opt to insert root account.

```
|----host-----|----user----|--Grant_priv--|--Super_priv--|
|-------------|------------|--------------|--------------|
|'192.168.%.%'| 'root'     | 'Y'          | 'Y'          |
|'localhost'  |'root'      | 'Y'          | 'Y'          |
|'127.0.0.1'  | 'root'     | 'Y'          | 'Y'          |
```

But when I use `grant replication slave on *.* to 'repl_user'@'192.168.%.%';`
I receive this error message `Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.%.%' (using password: YES)`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.%.%'
    IDENTIFIED BY '<password>'  
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` ?

Comment: I have tried,and return the same error.

Comment: okies. Are you able to connect to your test mysql database server using above root privileges?

Comment: Yes,I can use `insert,update,delete,create user`etc. ,except `grant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why,but after I restart the Server Machine,the problem has gone;